# Would waiting a few weeks to replace pads and rotors have damaged calipers?

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers

I took my Volvo s60 for regular 84k maintenance a few weeks ago and I requested to get my brakes and rotors checked. I was told that they needed to be replaced.

I booked an appointment for three weeks later, and even asked if it could wait till then. There was nothing wrong with the brakes, no squealing or anything.

When I took the car in for that appointment,  I was told that the caliper needed to be replaced, as I had gone too long with the brakes needing replacement. Is this normal, or am I getting screwed?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound normal to me, I can't see how low pads or worn discs could cause problems with the calipers (unless they were so worn that they were causing metal-on-metal braking and the extra heat caused problems, but then you'd have known something about it by the horrific noises it would have been making)

Comment: I agree with Nick C on this.  It may be that the technician has infact damaged a caliper performing the brake service.

Comment: Perfectly agree with Nick.